# Form not going into validation function onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a signup form, after inputting all the values, the `validation()`must validate the inputs and if all inputs are valid, should be redirected to home page, but my form is not entering the Javascript validation on submitting the form.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: black;}
* {box-sizing: border-box}

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    background: #C0C0C0;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
    background-color: #ffbf00;
    outline: none;
}

hr {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: darkgreen;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

button:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    padding: 14px 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}


/* Add padding to container elements */
.container {
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: white;
}

/* Clear floats */
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}



    .signupbtn {
       width: 50%;

    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validation() {

    alert('in..');
    var uname = document.signup_form.username.value;
    var mail= document.signup_form.email.value;
    var num= document.signup_form.phone.value;
    var pass= document.signup_form.psw.value;
    var des= document.signup_form.desg.value;

    alert('validating...');
    if allLetter(uname){
    if ValidateEmail(mail){
    if check_phonenumber(num){
    if CheckPassword(pass){
    if desgselect(des){
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    return false;
    }

function allLetter(uname)
{ 
    alert('validating username');
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(uname.value.match(letters))
        {
            alert('corret name');
            return true;
        }
    else
        {
            alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');
            uname.focus();
            return false;
        }
}

function ValidateEmail(mail) 
{
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(signup_form.email.value))
  {
    alert('valid mail ID');
    return (true)
  }
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
    return (false)
}

function check_phonenumber(num)
{
  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
  if((num.value.match(phoneno))
        {
        alert('valid phone number');
      return true;
        }
      else
        {
        alert("invalid phone number");
        return false;
        }
}

function CheckPassword(pass) 
{ 
var passw=  /^[A-Za-z]\w{7,15}$/;
if(pass.value.match(passw)) 
{ 
alert('Correct, try another...');
return true;
}
else
{ 
alert('Wrong...!');
return false;
}
}

function desgselect(des)
{
if(des.value == "Default")
{
alert('Select your designation from the list');
desg.focus();
return false;
}
else
{
alert('selected correct designation');
return true;
}
}

//}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="signup_form" onsubmit="return validation()" action="main.html" method="post" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
  <div class="container">
    <h1><center>Sign Up</center></h1>
    <p><center>Please fill in this form to create an account.</center></p>
    <hr>
    <label for="username"><b>Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your full name" name="username" required>
    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
    <label for="phone"><b>Phone</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" required><br>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

   <label for="desg"><b>Designation</b></label>
   <select name="desg">
    <option selected="" value="Default">(Please select your designation)</option>
    <option value="am">Asst. Manager</option>
    <option value="dm">Department Manager</option>
    <option value="mm"> Mart Manager</option>
    <option value="sp">Sales Person</option>
    </select><br>

    <br><label><b>Gender</b>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" > Male
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    </label>

    <p><center>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</center></p>

    <div class="clearfix" align="center">

      <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" onclick="validation(this.signup_form);"><b>Join Us</b></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried every possible way, but I am not able to resolve the problem.

Comment: There's no need to validate the `input`s if you are already using the `required` attribute. You should validate the form data again on the server side nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

When you have button type ="submit" in form, your click on submit button will refresh the page.
hence even if your validation function is executed you can not see error or success message.

what you need to do is prevent this default behaviour either with event.preventDefault() in validation method or change type of button to button.

In your case change button `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.

Answer (score 0):

You had many syntax errors in your code, which caused it to not execute.

You should also use `addEventListener` instead of an inline `onsubmit` event handler.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: black;}
* {box-sizing: border-box}

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    background: #C0C0C0;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
    background-color: #ffbf00;
    outline: none;
}

hr {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: darkgreen;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

button:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    padding: 14px 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}


/* Add padding to container elements */
.container {
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: white;
}

/* Clear floats */
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}



    .signupbtn {
       width: 50%;

    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validation() {

    alert('in..');
    var uname = document.signup_form.username.value;
    var mail= document.signup_form.email.value;
    var num= document.signup_form.phone.value;
    var pass= document.signup_form.psw.value;
    var des= document.signup_form.desg.value;

    alert('validating...');
    if (allLetter(uname)&&ValidateEmail(mail)&&check_phonenumber(num)&&CheckPassword(pass)&&desgselect(des)){
    return true;
    } 
    return false;
    }

function allLetter(uname){ 
    alert('validating username');
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(uname.match(letters))        {
            alert('corret name');
            return true;
        }else{
            alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');
            return false;
        }
}

function ValidateEmail(mail){
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(signup_form.email.value)){
    alert('valid mail ID');
    return (true);
  }
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
    return (false);
}

function check_phonenumber(num){
  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
  if(num.match(phoneno)){
        alert('valid phone number');
      return true;
     } else{
        alert("invalid phone number");
        return false;
        }
}

function CheckPassword(pass){ 
var passw=  /^[A-Za-z]\w{7,15}$/;
if(pass.match(passw)) { 
alert('Correct, try another...');
return true;
}else{ 
alert('Wrong...!');
return false;
}
}

function desgselect(des){
if(des == "Default"){
alert('Select your designation from the list');
desg.focus();
return false;
}else{
alert('selected correct designation');
return true;
}
}

//}
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("signupform").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
 validation();
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="signupform" name="signup_form" action="main.html" method="post" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
  <div class="container">
    <h1><center>Sign Up</center></h1>
    <p><center>Please fill in this form to create an account.</center></p>
    <hr>
    <label for="username"><b>Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your full name" name="username" required>
    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
    <label for="phone"><b>Phone</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" required><br>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

   <label for="desg"><b>Designation</b></label>
   <select name="desg">
    <option selected="" value="Default">(Please select your designation)</option>
    <option value="am">Asst. Manager</option>
    <option value="dm">Department Manager</option>
    <option value="mm"> Mart Manager</option>
    <option value="sp">Sales Person</option>
    </select><br>

    <br><label><b>Gender</b>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" > Male
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    </label>

    <p><center>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</center></p>

    <div class="clearfix" align="center">

      <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" onclick="validation(this.signup_form);"><b>Join Us</b></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```